# on visualising arithmetic with roots ansd radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, education

Is there a visual way to simplify $4\sqrt{12}+4\sqrt{27}$? I know the answer is $20\sqrt{3}$, but I want to geometrically explain it to a 14 year old.

Is there also a way to geometricaly interpret multiplication and division as well? Like $\sqrt{12}\cdot\sqrt{27}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{12}}{\sqrt{27}}$?

Comment: besides pulling the squared factors out of the square root?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's us not mix up things.  Your equation reduces to $\sqrt{12}+\sqrt{27}=5\sqrt{3}$, which follows from $\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{27}=3\sqrt{3}$.  So how to see $\sqrt{12}=2\sqrt{3}$?

Draw a square with sidelength $\sqrt{3}$, so it's area is $3$. Take $4$ of them to form a square with side length is $2\sqrt{3}$.  Now let your son compare:  the side length of the big square is by construction $2\sqrt{3}$, on the other hand it's area is $4\cdot3$, so it's side length is $\sqrt{4\cdot3}$.

Answer (score 0):

for multiplication, I would just construct a rectangle, which is easy since $\sqrt{n}$ is constructable.